# INSERT em duas tabelas - MySQL

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, trigger, relacionamento, modelo-relacional

Minha dúvida é relativamente simples, tenho 3 tabelas:
Disciplina, Professor e RelacionalPD.

O meu intuito era que quando houvesse um INSERT na tabela Disciplina OU Professor, o ID fosse enviado para essa tabela RelacionalPD, porém tive muitas tentativas e todas falhas.

Tentei criar TRIGGERS de todas as formas, uma que lembro de cabeça era que após um INSERT em uma dessas tabelas, o ID seria enviado para a RelacionalPD, porém, acontecia que a outra coluna da tabela RelacionalPD ficava com "NULL", daí se eu tentasse dar INSERT na outra coluna, uma linha era pulada, ou seja, isso iria quebrar a integridade do banco, aí está o banco:

[Imagem visual do meu banco pelo Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Of2w.jpg)

Enfim, o ponto é:
Existe alguma forma de inserir os dados na tabela RelacionalPD sem perder a integridade de dados? Mas que também não fosse de uma forma manual, infelizmente o professor da minha faculdade já está muito velho e não consegue manter a consistência na sua didática, espero que entendam e possam me ajudar. :) obrigado

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado. O ideal seria colocar o DDL.

Comment: Não precisa colocar o esquema todo, basta apenas o dessas 3 tabelas. Mas pelo que entendi sua dúvida é bem simples, já foi introduzido ao conceito de transação?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Julgo que não compreendeu a função da tabela `relacionalPD`. Sugiro que pesquise metodologias de criar relações entre tabelas. Nomeadamente relações 1-1, 1-N, N-1, N-M. O significado da tabela em causa é um caso típico.

Em relação ao erro que expõe. Analisando o diagrama que forneceu é visível que a tabela `relacionalPD` é composta por duas chaves estrangeiras (pista é a indicação `fk` - de `foreign key` - junto de cada uma das colunas que compõem a tabela), cada uma delas vindo das tabelas que compõem a relação definida na tabela (`professor` e `disciplina`).

Ao implementar a tabela `relacionalPD` com ambas chaves estrangeiras, criam-se duas restrições nos dados que a compõem. Restrições essas que têm de ser simultâneamente satisfeitas. Elas são:

- A coluna `id_professor` só pode receber valores que já existam na coluna `id_professor` da tabela `professor`, que é chave primária dessa tabela;
- A coluna `id_disciplina` só pode receber valores que já existam na coluna `id_disciplina` da tabela `disciplina`, que é chave primária dessa tabela;

Como, por definição, a chave primária das tabelas não pode ser `null`, não pode existir nenhuma entrada em qualquer uma das duas tabelas `disciplina` e `professor` que tenha o valor `id_disciplina` e `id_professor`, respectivamente, a `null`.

Por consequência, não se pode inserir na tabela `relacionalPD` entradas em que uma das duas colunas seja `null`.